# Python: extract MSB and LSB than convert in float

Tags: python, byte

I need your help! :)

This is my problem: after I read a pair of bytes (that are MSB and LSB) in hex (example 1 byte: 0x56) of my file. I need to obtain the number that the 2 bytes represent.

So this I want to do:

read file ---> get [byte][byte] --> obtain MSB and LSB --> convert in float

I'm new in python so I hope in your help. Bye!

Comment: Is `int('0x56', 16)` what you want?

Comment: what is the format of your file? binary file with two bytes in it? or a text file with two text numbers, e.g. 0x56 0x02, or 5602?

Comment: Yes, there are two hexadecimal bytes in 0x format

Comment: 0x56 0x02 or 5602 or x5602 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an input text file of

```
0x0102
```

this may be what you need

```
>>> with open('pp.txt') as f:
...  inp = f.read()
... 
>>> res = float(int(inp,16))
>>> res
258.0
```

which is quite close to what @user3100115 suggested from the beginning :)

Comment: if you think my answer solves your problem correctly and better than others', please mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: But you don't use MSB and LSB?

Comment: Immediately, give me the time to discover how to mark.

Comment: well, the way we interpret written numbers has the most significant digits on the left and least significant digits on the right, therefore the most significant byte is represented by the first two hex digits and the least significant byte by the last two